# SAML: Is it valid to route third party IdP messages through a single IdP

Tags: saml

My understanding of the SAML (v2) protocol is that Service Providers should be interacting directly with Identity Providers to exchange authorisation request and assertion messages.

I can think of a number of reasons why this would be a bad idea (undermines message signing, gives intermediate IdP access to info from other IdP), but are there any scenarios supported by SAML that would allows the following arrangement?

SP <------> MainIdP <------> ThirdPartyIdP

So (hypothetically) assuming that MainIdP has some clever way of determining that the SP user needs to authenticate against ThirdPartyIdP, it would delegate to the ThirdPartyIdP and then receive the response, process it and reply to the SP. Does SAML allow this? (I am asking because a software supplier has suggested this approach and I believe it isn't supported, as well as being fundamentally insecure.)

The "correct" approach as I understand it is for the SP to be configured to know about both IdPs independently, and either present the user with a list to pick from, or delegate to a Discovery Service which can ask the user, or infer by some other means, which IdP to use. Is this right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most federation identity providers for SAML have the concept of a "Home Realm Discovery" screen.

The SP is "bound" to the MainIdP but the MainIdP presents a screen which shows all the other IDP's that it is federated with. From that list, you pick the ThirdPartyIdP.